# Declare Array and Push in the Same Loop Statement

Tags: perl

## Declare Array and Push in the Same Statement

This obviously won't work:

```
push( my(@arr), '') for 0..$somenum;      # []
```

However, if we use a package variable, it'd give us the desired affect:

```
push( our(@arr), '') for 0..$somenum;     # ['','','', ...]
```

But it comes with unwanted side-effects.

---

Is there a reasonable, concise, all-in-one solution? Or is using two statements the best advice?

```
my @arr;
push( @arr, '' ) for 0..$somenum;         # ['','','', ...]
```

*I want to avoid multiple statements.  When there are many arrays being populated it looks cluttered and there is so much wasted space.*

---

I realize the above can be done without *push* (i.e., `my @arr = ('') x $somenum;`), but for different reasons, I wanted to use push.  [@texasbruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270003/texasbruce) made a good point that `map` would be better for something like this, even though there are debates about using *map* for that purpose.  Still, I look at this as a fun exercise.

Comment: Do you need to use `push`, or are you just looking to create and populate an array all at once?

Comment: For one liner use ruby :-)

Comment: Why don't you do my @arr = map ...

Comment: @Degustaf push, I updated the question

Comment: @texasbruce good question, I could do that, but for some reason I stupidly was trying to get push to work :)

Comment: I don't think this is a real problem, is it? The way to do this is with `('') x ($somenum+1)` but you want to do it a strange way that won't work *“for whatever reason*. If it is a requirement to use `push` then please explain. I also doubt if anyone would complain about `my @arr = map '', 0 .. $somenum`: it is using `map` when the returned list isn't used that is controversial

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: First, it is a real problem because I've asked it; you can see it above, it's real.  As per the SO guidelines on how to ask a question, I've simplified it and given an example of the bare essentials.  Repeating possible solutions that I've already listed in the question doesn't help :(  Also, the `x` is a repeater it wouldn't work with say, a value that you want to change.  Assume that `push` could be calling a function `push(our(@arr), rand ) for(0..3);`.  In that case `my @arr = (rand) x 3` would return the same random number, multiple times.  As stated, `map` could work, but controversial

Comment: @Sobrique I thought I was clear in: *I want to avoid multiple statements. When there are many arrays being populated it looks cluttered and there is so much wasted space.* To make clear, concise code.  Push is also, much more understood by the person maintaining the code, than map is.

Comment: If you're doing the same thing for a bunch of arrays, why not use a loop?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it's not exactly the same

Comment: Protip: Waste more space. It makes code more readable. Compressing everything into the minimal bytecount makes code harder to understand.

Comment: @Sobrique thank you for your opinion.  I think that `push( my(@arr), '') for 0..3; ` is much more readable (and more of a protip) than `my @arr;\n push( @arr, '') for 0..3;`

Comment: @vol7ron How different is it? Is `$somenum` simply different for each array? Could you give a more concrete example?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot consider multiple different arrays pulling data from multiple different places.  The format is somewhat the same, but sanitation functions might be different.

Comment: Also, whomever voted to close, you are incorrect in your reasoning and downvotes are welcome, but suggested improvements are much more appreciated.

Comment: If you have a genuine reason to avoid the obvious solution of `my @arr = ('') x ($somenum+1)` then please explain. If this is just *“a fun exercise”* then you are wasting our time with a bizarre goal

Comment: `sub { push @{$_[0]}, '' for 0..$somenum }->( my @arr );`. It's actually two statements, but they're nested.

Comment: Oops, that should be `->( \my @arr )`

Comment: @Borodin unless you're being paid to answer questions, I don't see how it's wasting anyone's time.  Questions on StackOverflow do not ***need*** to be answered by you.  They are there and you can pick and choose which ones you wish to contribute your information towards.  Though, I am by all means appreciative of your time and intellect, so I thank you and am sorry that a *fun exercise* is seen as a waste of time to you.  If the answer was simple, I wouldn't have asked, I'm sure Google would turn up something and my end goal is to reduce the lines of code, but still keep it clear/maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my ... for ...` is officially undefined behaviour.

> NOTE: The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...`) is **undefined**. The value of the `my` variable may be `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

(Emphasis in original.)

To assign values to a new array, use an assignment.

```
my @arr = ('') x ($somenum+1);
```

If the values to assign vary, use `map`.

```
my @arr = map { 2*$_ } 0..$somenum;
```

Comment: I suppose map is the closest to a push/loop structure, I just hate to use it when I can avoid it.  For maintainability, I would rather `my( @foo, @bar, @foobar );  push (@foo, ...) for ...; push(@bar...) ...; push(@foobar, ...) for ...;` because I think people coming from another language would understand that much quicker than what's happening in the map statement.

Comment: Trying to make Perl look like another language is not a good thing.

Comment: Agreed, but no one suggested that.  Also, expecting everyone to be an expert in every language is also not a good thing.  There is syntax that is common in many languages and using it can often be more advantageous (and less costly) than something that is considered syntactical sugar.  Code is written by humans to be understood by humans.

Comment: No one is doing `for (my $i=0; $i<3; $i++){ push(@foo, rand); }` which is almost universally more recognizable.

Comment: @vol7ron, Yes, I already pointed out that you're not even practicing what you preach.

Comment: Because relativism and moderation are philosophies I like to respect.   There are tradeoffs and that's exactly what I'm practicing.  Would you suggest Perl golf?  I would think not. Why; it's Perl and applying all that is is perl?  Because there are limits and extremes.  I think Conway had a good pbp book where he may have discussed this.  I also would not expect everyone to understand some concepts Dominus wrote in his book.   Unless the application demands it, keeping it simple is often more advantageous.  The reason for my initial question was to reduce clutter, but still maintainable.

Comment: Even Conway says PHB shouldn't be followed, that it has bad advice. What he hopes you take out of his book is an ability to judge readability. Similarity to other languages is a good tie breaker, but it takes a back seat to many other factors. Especially since Perl is extremely different from other languages.

Comment: I don't know what PHB is, but there was a lot of backlash in the community against some of the more minor aspects of his book.  It's a guide, not an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you should be using

```
my @arr = ('') x ($somenum+1);
```

for the case where all the elements are the same, and

```
my @arr = map rand, 0 .. $somenum;
```

for the case you cited where the values are different

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this will work other than using `push` as an assignment operator.

```
push my @arr, ('') x ($somenum+1);
```

For something similar to what you are trying with a postfixed for loop, the array will be lexically scoped within the loop and go out of scope immediately.

Comment: @vol7ron: What does your comment mean? Degustaf's point is that you have written a `for` loop and any `my` declaration will be scoped within it, so you cannot do what you're asking

Comment: It's basically the same as `my ... if ...;`, which is officially undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Borodin his statement, `For something similar to what you are trying with a postfixed for loop, the array will be lexically scoped within the loop and go out of scope immediately.`, is very important because I didn't mention anything about the *loop* in the question (only listed it in the stripped example), but that was a very important part and needed to be mentioned in the title or somewhere in the question.  Without the loop, the declaration would not repeatedly happen and overwrite the variable.

Comment: That's awful code because it's misleading because it uses push to perform an assignment. :(

Comment: @ikegami I agree that it's awful code.  I was actually trying to point it out as an abusive way to accomplish what OP wanted, despite there being less convoluted approaches.